# 1st Order Differential Equation - Existence and Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following 1st order differential equation:

$$y'=(x-4y)^{-2}$$

Which isn't continuous when $y=\frac{x}{4}$. Nevertheless, solutions exist and are unique on all the plane. How's that?

Answer (score 2):

The theorem says "If certain conditions hold, then you get existence and uniqueness of solutions," but it's not an if-and-only-if. It's more like the statement "If it's my birthday, I'll have cake for dessert," which happens to be true. But I also sometimes have cake for dessert on other days. So merely seeing me eat cake doesn't allow you to conclude that it's my birthday.

Comment: How can I solve the problem then?

Comment: I thought your problem was that there was an apparent contradiction between the theorem and the fact that this equation has solutions. Is your actual problem that you need to find all solutions to this ODE?

Comment: I'm asked for the general solution to this differential equation and where such solutions exist and are unique.

Comment: Looks as if @Amzoti's given you a good start towards a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Substitute

$$v(x)= x - 4y(x) \rightarrow v' = 1 - 4y'$$

Substitute these into the ODE, solve for $v$ and then solve for $y$.

**Spoiler**

> $$ x+\ln(-x+4 y(x)+2)-\ln(x-4 y(x)+2)-4 y(x) = x+c$$

A little more simplification is possible, but left in this form so you can follow.